# JavaString loop through string and break string into sub strings

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to loop through set of strings and break them into sub strings by removing two characters and storing them into an array.
lets say two stings are returned, the number of characters will always be multiple of 2.

```
AADDFFCC
GGDD
```

The first string will give me `AADDFF,AADD,AA`
The second string will give me `GG`.
i want to store all sub string into a single array.
So based upon above example i should end up with.
**`subString = ["AADDFF","AADD","AA","GG"]`**
This is my incomplete attempt.

```
var StringArray = ["AADDFFCC","GGDD"] //this could be indefinite length
var subString = [];
var StringArrayLength = StringArray.length;
var loopCurrentString;
var loopCurrentSubString

for (var i = 0; i < StringArrayLength; i += 2) {

loopCurrentString = StringArray[i];

 loopCurrentSubString = loopCurrentString.substring(0, loopCurrentString.length - 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an implementation with nested `for loops`:

```js
const data = ["AADDFFCC", "GGDD"]
const endResult = []

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j += 2) {
    if (j != 0)
      endResult.push(data[i].slice(0, data[i].length - j))
  }
}

console.log(endResult)
```

You could do this by using [**`reduceRight`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) to chunk the array into the desired pieces starting from the right side:

```js
const data = ["AADDFFCC","GGDD"]

const chunkBy = (arr, by=2) => [...arr].reduceRight((r,c,i,a) => 
  ((((a.length-1) - i)%by == 0 && a.length-1 != i) ? 
  r.push(a.slice(0, i+1).reduce((r,c) => `${r}${c}`)) : 
  0, r),[])
 
console.log(data.reduce((r,c) => [...chunkBy(r), ...chunkBy(c)]))
```

And on the end stitch them together via ES6 spread operator.

Comment: Hi Akrion, The code actually works but i am looking for solution in pure javascript without using any library

Comment: Not sure what you mean but this is pure javascript. It just is using the latest specification which is referred to as ES6. reduceRight is a method of `Array.prototype`. Or you are saying you want to solve this via `for` loop?

Comment: @HakanSukar added implementation with nester for loops as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < StringArrayLength; i ++) {
  //get element
  loopCurrentString = StringArray[i];
  //add substrings in the array
  while(loopCurrentString.length>2){
    loopCurrentSubString = loopCurrentString.substring(0, loopCurrentString.length - 2);
    substring.push(loopCurrentSubString);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Kristian, when you try running the script, it times out, so if you want to print the substring array, it just times out

Comment: I think the while loop doesnt move forward